# Failed trying to echo simple php

Tags: php, if-statement, get, echo

I know I am doing something wrong and I know a var does not work that way but I can't for the life of me remember how to make it work, it would be much appreciated if someone would point out what I am doing wrong.

```
    $me1 {
       if($_GET){ echo $_GET['u']; } 
       if(!$_GET){ echo "username"; } 
    };

    echo $me1;
```

Comment: That isn't even close to valid PHP syntax. Where did you get that from?

Comment: @JohnConde It might be a bit off, but the syntax is valid.

Comment: @cwallenpoole: heck no. try it. "unexpected T_IF".

Comment: @MarcB `php -r '$me=1; {if($_GET){echo 1;} if(!$_GET) {echo 2;} } echo $me;' #outputs 21` `php -v
PHP 5.3.28 (cli) (built: Dec 17 2013 00:28:38) `

Comment: That is not at all what the OP has. `$me1 { if(...); }` is a flat out syntax error.

Comment: `php -r '$me; {if($_GET){echo 1;} if(!$_GET) {echo 2;} } echo $me;' #outputs 2`

Comment: @MarcB OK, I see my error. I added a semi-colon after `$me1`. That makes the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I looking to do as I explained in the original question I was looking how to display the $_GET result is as little code as possible.

So rather than typing it all out again and again I could quickly refer to my code. To do this I am using a function and I just need to reference `displayUser();` when I want to use the code again.

```
<?php
    function displayUser() {
        echo (isset($_GET['u'])) ? $_GET['u'] : "username";
    }

    displayUser();
?>
```

So `http://example.com/?u=alex`will display `alex` wherever I call the function `displayUser();`

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
if(isset($_GET['u'])){
    $me1 = $_GET['u'];
}else{
    $me1 = "username";
}
```

Comment: You will also want to run !empty() on that $_GET.  It can easily be set but without a value to assign.

Comment: I am now using.

 if(isset($_GET['u'])){
     $me1 = $_GET['u'];
 }else{
     $me1 = "username";
 }

 echo $me1;

Thanks everyone for your help. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this ternary syntax:

```
echo (isset($_GET['u'])) ? $_GET['u'] : "username";
```

Comment: echo (isset($_GET['u'])) ? $_GET['u'] : "username";

I am using your way now, but I want a way to echo this because it need to be short as I am echoing it many times.

Comment: This will echo either $_GET['u'] or the string "username". Try it and it will echo properly.

Comment: That's not what I meant. I am trying to allow the code to echo from the above with as little text as possible for viewing reasons and to keep the code simple and tidy. http://puu.sh/8neVN.png